# Playing several tracks saved locally in sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I need to play n tracks one after another with ability to switch to next/previous song and pause. Songs are located in Documents folder.

I looked in `AVQueuePlayer`, but it seems that this approach is not working with local files, playing by url works fine. Now i can play one song with `AVAudioPlayer` like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[node path]];
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[self.player play];
```

But it seems that playing bunch of tracks one after another this way is not the best practice.

May be there are frameworks that implement this in more convenient way?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) is probably what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i needed.